# How do I add a body class to specific pages?

Tags: page-template

Here is what I have so far in my functions.php.

```
add_filter('body_class','cp_new_body_classes');
function cp_new_body_classes($classes) {
    if( !is_page_template() ) {
        $classes[] = 'reg-page';
    return $classes;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to append the class of `reg-page` to pages that are not page templates. For the pages that *are* page templates, I just want to leave the classes as they are. When trying the code above, the class of `reg-page` gets added like I want to pages which are not page templates but the other pages (which *are* page templates) get left with no classes at all. How can I fix this code?

Comment: You should put your answer as an answer to your question (in the answer form) and accept it, to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('body_class','cp_new_body_classes');
function cp_new_body_classes($classes) {
    if( !is_page_template() )
        $classes[] = 'reg-page';

    return $classes;
}
```

The problem was that you are only returning the classes if `!is_page_template()`, but you want to return the classes always as it contains the other classes you didn't add yourself in an array, you just want to add some then return them like normal.

Comment: yup, always return $classes